# Laravel Query Builder vs Laravel Eloquent ORM in many to many relation

Tags: laravel

Hi i want to get same result in join query builder as we get in many to many eloquent orm..

```
$users = DB::table('users')->join('role_user','users.id','=','role_user.user_id')
                               ->join('roles','roles.id','=','role_user.role_id')
                               ->get();
```

if I use this then I got separate array for same user with role.. for example XYZ user has 3 role then it give me 3 array of same user.
[image]

but I want to get it like this user has 3 roles like eloquent

Comment: you can use laraval relationships with models

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel relationship in view file for that you need to define relationship in user  model

```
  public function userRoles(){
$this->hasMany(UserRole::class);
}
```

in controller you need to use With that eager load userRole
To get user roles in view file

```
$user->userRole
```

// this will return array of user role related to that user